# Conditional insert of rows in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am interested in creating new rows is SAS that are conditional on specific variables.

Suppose these are the names of the columns RecordID, ItemName, ItemCount, ItemX, ItemY, ItemZ.
ItemX, ItemY, and ItemZ are numeric variables that can be equal to or greater than 0.
When ItemX, ItemY, and/or ItemZ holds a value greater than 0, I want a new row to be created where ItemName contains the variable name (ItemX, ItemY, ItemZ) and ItemCount to contain the numeric value.

For example, if RecordNumber=1 has ItemX=5 and ItemY=10, then ItemName=ItemX and ItemCount=5 will appear in a new row. ItemName=ItemY and ItemCount=10 has its own row.

How should I go about this in SAS? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
data want(keep=ItemName ItemCount);
set have;
array items[3] itemx itemy itemz;
format ItemName $32. ItemCount best.;

do i=1 to 3;
   if items[i] > 0 then do;
      ItemName = vname(items[i]);
      ItemCount = items[i];
      output;
   end;
end;
run;
```

Create an array of the item variables.  Loop over that array. Check your condition. Use the `vname()` function to get the variable name and the `output` statement to create the output record.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are intending to do.
<yoda>
You seek PROC TRANSPOSE.
</yoda>